# How to enumerate all components in a base form (even those added in derived form)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there a way to enumerate all components on a .NET form object and change some of its properties in c#? A method in the base form should be able to enumerate all components including those that are added in a derived form.

Like Delphi, C# in .NET can list all visual controls in a form.

Delphi: `Self.Controls[i];` *//where i = 0 to ControlCount-1*

c#: `foreach(Control c in Controls) {}`

In both these languages/technologies, this can be used in a **base form** method to list all Controls that are even added on a derived form.

So far so good, but this does not work the same way with non-visual components.

In Delphi it is possible to list all non-visual components by:

`Self.Components[i];` *//where i = 0 to ComponentCount-1*. *Note that the list includes all components that are added in the derived form as well.*

It does not work in a similar fashion in c#. You can use the form's `components` container to get some information about *some* of the components - only those components which used the `System.ComponentModel.Container`. It does not list all the components. e.g., DevArt's MySQL components which are not created using the `ComponentsModel.Container` cannot be enumerated.

Moreover, in any case, those components which are added to the derived form cannot be enumerated in the base object, even when they are created using *ComponentModel.Container* because *ComponentModel.Container* instances are local to each form object.

Comment: Can you list any component you use that wasn't add to `Form.Components`?

Comment: You are right it cannot be done. That is a flaw in .NET architecture. It could have been handled the same way Controls are implemented. Whether or not the component designer adopt IContainer concept, since the designer is creating those objects, Windows forms could very well add it to a standalone array just like it was done in Delphi. The only way I know of is to traverse using reflection.

Answer (score -1):

did you try reflection?

```
 private IEnumerable<Component> EnumerateComponents() {
        return from field in GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
               where typeof(Component).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType)
               let component = (Component)field.GetValue(this)
               where component != null
               select component;
    }
```